# Using select_and_order and foreign table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I recently switched to Backpack for Laravel and am faced with a problem displaying the content of a `select_and_order` field.

I have 3 tables:

- `users` table.
- `items` table.
- `user_items` table, which defines three columns:

  - `user_id` as a foreign key for the `users` table
  - `order_number`. A number which we use to sort orders
  - `items`: A JSON array containing all the `items` ids

The primary key for the `user_items` table is a composition of the `user_id` and the `order_number`. That way, we can reduce duplicates.

My major challenge is how to display the `select_and_order` field values:
I currently use:

```php
$this->crud->addField([
    'label' => 'Items',
    'type' => 'select_and_order',
    'name' => 'items',
    'model' => UserItem::class, // Defined a model to handle this
    'attribute' => 'items',
    'entity' => 'items',
    'options' => Item::get()->pluck("name", "id")->toArray()
]);
```

The list of items display but the values are empty, even when the `user_items->items` have values

Comment: Hey there. Are you casting the field `items` to array in your model ?

Comment: Hi there Pedro. Yes I am 

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, I switched to using a pivot table and defining an accessor to handle this